# properties are not passed to props / REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-props

In the main component I want to pass the title and price via props, why doesn't it work?

What did I miss?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTjDm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwxaG.png)

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
const Categories = () => {
    return (
        <div className="content__items">
            <PizzaBlock title="Мексиканская" price="500"/>
            <PizzaBlock title="Мексиканская" price="500"/>
            <PizzaBlock/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
const PizzaBlock = (props) => {
const [pizzaItem, setpizzaItem] = useState([{
    title: 'Вегатарианская',
    price: '499р',
    id: '1'
}]);
   
    return (
        <div className="pizza-block">
            <img
                className="pizza-block__image"
                src="https://dodopizza-a.akamaihd.net/static/Img/Products/Pizza/ru-RU/b750f576-4a83-48e6-a283-5a8efb68c35d.jpg"
                alt="Pizza"
            />
            {pizzaItem.map((item) => (
                <PizzaItemBlock key={item.id} {...item}/>
            ))}


        </div>
    )
}
```

```
const PizzaItemBlock = ({title,price}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <h4 className="pizza-block__title">{title}</h4>
            <div className="pizza-block__selector">
                <ul>
                    <li className="active">тонкое</li>
                    <li>традиционное</li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li className="active">26 см.</li>
                    <li>30 см.</li>
                    <li>40 см.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="pizza-block__bottom">
                <div className="pizza-block__price">{price}</div>
                <div className="button button--outline button--add">
                    <svg
                        width="12"
                        height="12"
                        viewBox="0 0 12 12"
                        fill="none"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    >
                        <path
                            d="M10.8 4.8H7.2V1.2C7.2 0.5373 6.6627 0 6 0C5.3373 0 4.8 0.5373 4.8 1.2V4.8H1.2C0.5373 4.8 0 5.3373 0 6C0 6.6627 0.5373 7.2 1.2 7.2H4.8V10.8C4.8 11.4627 5.3373 12 6 12C6.6627 12 7.2 11.4627 7.2 10.8V7.2H10.8C11.4627 7.2 12 6.6627 12 6C12 5.3373 11.4627 4.8 10.8 4.8Z"
                            fill="white"
                        />
                    </svg>
                    <span>Добавить</span>
                    <i>2</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: You're not using `props` anywhere.

Comment: why =/
tell me how to do it right plz
 @Spikatrix

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your props down into PizzaBlock, but you are not then passing them down further into PizzaItemBlock. Therefore there will be no data to display.

If you change your code to this, it should work:

```
const PizzaBlock = ({title, price}) => {
const [pizzaItem, setpizzaItem] = useState([{
title: 'Вегатарианская',
price: '499р',
id: '1'
}]);

return (
    <div className="pizza-block">
        <img
            className="pizza-block__image"
            src="https://dodopizza-a.akamaihd.net/static/Img/Products/Pizza/ru-RU/b750f576-4a83-48e6-a283-5a8efb68c35d.jpg"
            alt="Pizza"
        />
        {pizzaItem.map((item) => (
            <PizzaItemBlock key={item.id} {...item} title={title} price={price}/>
        ))}


    </div>
)
```

}

Comment: If you pass title and price and props, then you should probably remove the state?

Comment: Yes, I've done it already. Thanks, it works @Disco

Answer (score 0):

You pass the props `title="Мексиканская" price="500"` from `Categories` to `PizzaBlock`.
But in the `PizzaBlock`, you didn't use that `props` to pass to the `PizzaItemBlock`.

```
const PizzaBlock = (props) => {
    const [pizzaItem, setpizzaItem] = useState([{
        title: 'Вегатарианская',
        price: '499р',
        id: '1'
    }]);
       
        return (
            <div className="pizza-block">
                <img
                    className="pizza-block__image"
                    src="https://dodopizza-a.akamaihd.net/static/Img/Products/Pizza/ru-RU/b750f576-4a83-48e6-a283-5a8efb68c35d.jpg"
                    alt="Pizza"
                />
                {pizzaItem.map((item) => (
                    <PizzaItemBlock key={item.id} {...item}/>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

According to the above code, you pass the `props` set in `state` variable `pizzaItem` (`title="Вегатарианская" price="499р"`)

I will modify the `PizzaBlock` component like this.

```
const PizzaBlock = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="pizza-block">
            <img
                className="pizza-block__image"
                src="https://dodopizza-a.akamaihd.net/static/Img/Products/Pizza/ru-RU/b750f576-4a83-48e6-a283-5a8efb68c35d.jpg"
                alt="Pizza"
            />
            <PizzaItemBlock {...props}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```